# $.grep to check if object exists in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I am trying to build an array of objects and then either update the object or create a new one depending if one does not exist. This is my first time trying to use the $.grep function and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any Advice?

Here are the objects:

```
function Phase(phase, html, count) {
        this.phase = phase;
        this.html = html;
        this.count = count;
        this.porfolios = [];
    }

    function Portfolio(portfolio, html, count) {
        this.portfolio = portfolio;
        this.html = html;
        this.count = count;
    }
```

Here is the code in question....

```
var phases = [];
//Check Array of Phases 
result = $.grep(phases, function (e) { return e.phase == item.Phase; });

if (result.length == 0) 
{
     var newphase = Phase(item.Phase, itemhtml, 1)
     phases.push(newphase);
} 
else if (result.length == 1) 
{
 // update existing phase
 result[0].count ++;
 result[0].html += itemhtml;
}
```

Comment: What does it do or what doesn't it do? What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you create a demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newphase = Phase(item.Phase, itemhtml, 1)
```

should be

```
var newphase = new Phase(item.Phase, itemhtml, 1)
```

Comment: yep, stupid mistake... sometimes it just takes another set of eyes i guess.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `new` keyword to create an object:

```
var newphase = new Phase(item.Phase, itemhtml, 1);
```